# Mod_Rewrite and website links structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a website with this structre

index.php / home.php / profile.php / news.php / photos.php

newsfeed.php - for news article

photo.php - for photo

there is also username for users to get short link for his profile like

```
mysite.com/UserName
```

now I'm using this code in .htaccess to rewrite URLS of username

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

now I want to rewrite all my links to be SE-Friendly like this

```
index.php   --> index
home.php    --> home
photos.php  --> photos
videos.php  --> videos

newsfeed.php?id=xx  --> news/xx
photo.php?id=xx     --> photo/xx
```

So any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ newsfeed.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^photo/([0-9]+)/?$ photo.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/?$ videos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php [L]
```

And just add them on like so.